# Hazelcast unable to connect to other cluster members

Tags: java, caching, microservices, grpc, hazelcast

i have 2 micro-service applications which connect with gRPC .I want to enable Hazelcast caching on this.However hazelcast in my application which acts as gRPC server is unabale to connect with that application which acts as gRPC client

hazelcast.yml of gRPC server application

```
hazelcast:
    cluster-name: banks_data
    network:
      port:
        auto-increment: true
        port-count: 20
        port: 9701
      join:
        multicast:
          enabled: false
        tcp-ip:
          enabled: true
          connection-timeout-seconds: 60000
          member-list:
            - 127.0.0.1:9701
            - 127.0.0.1:9702
```

hazelcast.yml of applictaion which alos acts as gRPC Client

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: banks_data
  network:
    public-address: 127.0.0.1:9702
    port:
      port: 9702
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
```

Below is my error logs

```
023-05-29 17:04:07.631  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [banks_data] [4.0.2] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
2023-05-29 17:04:07.637  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [banks_data] [4.0.2] Picked [127.0.0.1]:9701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=9701], bind any local is true
2023-05-29 17:04:07.658  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Hazelcast 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) starting at [127.0.0.1]:9701
2023-05-29 17:04:07.658  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2023-05-29 17:04:07.831  INFO 24828 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Backpressure is disabled
2023-05-29 17:04:08.070  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Creating TcpIpJoiner
2023-05-29 17:04:08.071  WARN 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem             : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
2023-05-29 17:04:08.353  INFO 24828 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Starting 12 partition threads and 7 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2023-05-29 17:04:08.357  INFO 24828 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2023-05-29 17:04:08.363  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] [127.0.0.1]:9701 is STARTING
2023-05-29 17:04:08.417  INFO 24828 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:9702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2023-05-29 17:04:08.418  INFO 24828 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] Could not connect to: /127.0.0.1:9702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: no further information to address /127.0.0.1:9702]
2023-05-29 17:04:08.419  INFO 24828 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner    : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] [127.0.0.1]:9702 is added to the blacklist.
2023-05-29 17:04:09.415  INFO 24828 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [127.0.0.1]:9701 - 88660304-9ec4-461a-a580-8a4d52cad7d0 this
]

2023-05-29 17:04:09.426  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:9701 [banks_data] [4.0.2] [127.0.0.1]:9701 is STARTED
2023-05-29 17:04:09.583  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-29 17:04:09.812  INFO 24828 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-29 17:04:09.904  INFO 24828 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by commenting hazelcast.yml in client application and instead declared hazellcast configs using beans

```
import com.hazelcast.config.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig(){
        NetworkConfig networkConfig = new NetworkConfig();
        MulticastConfig multicastConfig = new MulticastConfig();
        multicastConfig.setEnabled(false);
        networkConfig.getJoin().setMulticastConfig(multicastConfig);
        TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = new TcpIpConfig();
        tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);
        tcpIpConfig.addMember("127.0.0.1");
        networkConfig.setPort(9702);
        networkConfig.getJoin().setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);

        return new Config()
                .setClusterName(BanksDataConstants.BANKS_DATA)
                .setNetworkConfig(networkConfig)
                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
                        .setName(BanksDataConstants.BANKS_DATA)
                        .setBackupCount(0)
                        .setMaxIdleSeconds(0)
                                .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig().setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU))
                                .setMergePolicyConfig(new MergePolicyConfig().setPolicy(MergePolicyConfig.DEFAULT_MERGE_POLICY))
               
                );


    }
}
```